# Multiple splits in the same line of code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert this:
`/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/csvbill/audit_process/inwork_20150921141500/LGNP.SMR.CSV0000.BILL.INPUT01.kb01^^.20150921140115.xml`

To this:
`kb01^^.20150921140115`

Currently I'm achieving this by doing the following:

```
cur_file = '/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/csvbill/audit_process/inwork_20150921141500/LGNP.SMR.CSV0000.BILL.INPUT01.kb01^^.20150921140115.xml'
file_path = cur_file.split('/')
file_name = file_path[-1].split('.')
project_code = file_name[5] + '.' + file_name[6]
```

Can it be done in one step?

Comment: how do you know what fields to get.  other than the .xml suffix it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Your code on one line:

```
project_code = '.'join(curr_file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-3:-1])
```

Because the `split()` function returns a list of strings, you can use immediately address `string.split()[n]` which is then just another string, so you can then apply `string.split()[].split()[]` until you've reached where you want to be.

So that's what's been done above. The last `[-3:-1]` just indexes from the end, to always remove the `.xml`.

The `'.'.join()` is a way of putting the period back in, while also making the result a single string.

As there is no reason to `split('/')` when you are going to `split('.')` later, you could shorten it to just:

```
project_code = '.'join(curr_file.split('.')[-3:-1])
```

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Because of the object oriented nature of Python, you can 'stack' functions to the end of other functions.

Answer (score 2):

something like this `'.'.join(cur_file.split('.')[-3:-1])` ?

Answer (score 1):

the path splitting could also be done using `os.path` (`os.path.basename(cur_file)` returns the file name part of a path):

```
import os.path

cur_file = '/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/csvbill/audit_process/inwork_20150921141500/' +\
           'LGNP.SMR.CSV0000.BILL.INPUT01.kb01^^.20150921140115.xml'

print '.'.join(os.path.basename(cur_file).split('.')[5:7])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s="/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/csvbill/audit_process/inwork_20150921141500/LGNP.SMR.CSV0000.BILL.INPUT01.kb01^^.20150921140115.xml"

print(s.split(".",5)[-1].rsplit(".",1)[0])
```

If you know there are always 4 characters to remove from the end:

```
print(s.split(".",5)[-1][:-4])
```

Or:

```
print(".".join(s.rsplit(".",3)[1:-1]))
```

Or using str.format and unpacking:

```
print("{}.{}".format(*s.rsplit(".", 3)[1:]))
```

If any string is not in the format you have posted, this and every other answer will most likely fail.

Answer (score 0):

I will introduce you to the great power of regular expressions, but fear not, they are here to help.

Without prior knowledge of how your other paths look like, we can asume that the project code is the last bit of the path, and it is composed of a arbitrary string between two dots and a series of numbers between a dot an the extension, so a regular expression to capture this would be:

```
import re
exp = re.compile(ur'.+\.(.+\.\d+).xml')
```

Then you can use that compiled regular expression to find the matching tokens in your string, in just one line:

```
project_name = re.findall(exp, cur_file)[0]
```